# What is the change in jtds-1.3.1.jar for PreparedStatment?

Tags: java, jtds

I upgraded from jtds-1.2.5.jar to jtds-1.3.1.jar. After this I can see that JVM is taking more memory in its heap.

Please look into this code:

```
PreparedStatement ptmt = null;
query = "select * from table1";
try {
    while (<condition>) 
    {
       pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query); //**creating huge amount of instance and failed to close in loop**
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {}
finally {
    <pstmt close statement>
}
```

My question is, What about the created huge number of instances?

1. It will be in live or garbage collectable?
2. If it is garbage collectable, then When it will be cleared from memory?
3. Is there any behavior change in jtds-1.3.1.jar?

Comment: How about reading jtds changelog? What is the use of this "code"?

Comment: I just added a block of code here. In the above loop, I will fetch values from DB and do some operations

Comment: You should update you sample code to be more meaningful, as is, I don't see why one would need such code.

Comment: why don't you simply close the prepared statement in the loop - no need to speculate when the GC clears the statement.

Comment: You should never ever rely on the GC to clean up after you. Close your statements as soon as you no longer need them. Not closing them and letting the GC handle it for you is a bug in your code. That's true for any class that implements `AutoCloseable`.